# Is it OK to use "so" twice in immediate succession? --"I'm not saying so, so you quit your job"

Tags: word-usage, redundancy

Is it OK to use **so** twice in immediate succession?

> I'm not saying so, so you quit your job.

And does it sound better with *this* in place of the first *so*?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to say in your example sentence.  Please add more detail.

Comment: Why? doesn't the first so refer to something said earlier, and the second a conjunction meaning "with the intent that"?

Comment: The two clauses of your sentence do not seem logically related. Also, the progressive is confusing in the first clause. *She did not wear a jacket, so she got cold when the day became cloudy*.  Your first clause does not seem to be an explanation for fact expressed in the second clause, in that manner.

Comment: It would be perfectly acceptable to say: *I didn't say so, so don't blame me". Or to say: *The children have been so, so good!*

Comment: Are you trying to say "I did not tell you to quit your job" or "I'm not saying (that) you should quit your job" ?

Comment: I'm trying to say: I didn't say that, so that (= to make) you quit.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have so, so in a sentence. However what you are trying to say (looking at your comment on your question): "I didn't say that, so that (= to make) you quit."  asks for different wording, for example:

- "I didn't say that to make you quit."
- "I didn't say that, for you to quit."

The problem is, in a sentence like "**He** did that, *so* **she** did that." in English this means, he did something and then as a matter of fact she did something in reaction. In other languages the word so after the comma may imply that his intention was that she would react, but in English this is not the case!

Comment: What if we add **will**: He did that (yawned), so she **will** do this (leave)? doesn't this make _so_ introduce a desired effect? And is _so_ _that_ different from _so_? As in, I'm giving you more information, so (that) you will understand it better. Doesn't so that introduce a desired effect, that is to help/make you understand.

Comment: yes, _so that_ is different from simply _so_! Without _that_ it is really only telling what the logical consequence is and not implying an intention.

Comment: +1 for better suggestions. There is extra ambiguity in the original sentence because "quit" has the same form for present and past tense. This answer's suggestions avoid this ambiguity.